# Dual Channel Relay Python Script

Tags: raspbian, python, apache-httpd, relay

I am a Python noob, and recently purchased a 2 channel relay module from [sunfounder](http://www.sunfounder.com/index.php?c=show&id=6&model=2%20Channel%20Relay). I wired it up to my Pi, and the relay turned on and stays on. I am wondering if any one can provide my with the simplest Python code to flip the relay on and off.

Extra Info:
I am connected to pins 2 (5V), 6 (Ground), and 9 (Ground) on a Raspberry Pi Model B.

I followed the [instructions](http://www.sunfounder.com/index.php?c=show&id=6&model=2%20Channel%20Relay)

Comment: Those pins are not controllable in software so there is no possibility of providing a working script.  Perhaps you should do some more research and try writing your own script. Post your script if it doesn't work.

Comment: this might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oaf_zQcrg7g or this http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=63315  or this google search https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=raspberry+pi+relay+python

Comment: What pins should I connect to? Those were the ones that the instructables article told me to do (it wanted me to use it over html, but I want a python script). Thanks

Comment: http://cdn.instructables.com/FMI/MQFI/HMMFAEYL/FMIMQFIHMMFAEYL.MEDIUM.jpg is from the instructions you were following.  Why didn't you follow instructions and use the same pins (i.e. GPIO7)?

Comment: I did, but it didn't work.

Comment: According to your question, you used PIN 9 (Ground), not PIN 7 (GPIO7)

Comment: @drcomputer - please do post an answer with the solution.

Comment: @drcomputer, I'll be interested to hear if you get your project completed.  I want to do the same thing, but I like this tutorial a little better: http://www.driscocity.com/idiots-guide-to-a-raspberry-pi-garage-door-opener/

Answer (score 1):

First off, your pins are messed up - so you need to connect the Vcc to a 5V pin and the GND to a ground pin. Then you connect your two relays to a GPIO pin. For instance, I connected my two to GPIO 2 and 3. Then use the [python scripts](https://github.com/skiwithpete/relaypi/tree/master/16port) supplied by ["skiwithpete" on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/skiwithpete), see this video [Raspberry Pi: 16 Channel Relay how to with example software for automation projects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFt480sxNWg).

Comment: I have taken the liberty of adding the links to which I believe you are referring to. Please correct me if I am wrong.